# Two OSM tile servers, same world import different size databases

Tags: gis, openstreetmap, postgis, postgresql-9.3

Got a strange issue here, and it makes me wonder if an import went bad or if some indexes are missing on one server.

Server 1 has a World Import that DB is about 505 GB in size.
Server 2 has the same World Import but its DB is 650 GB in size.

Both were imported using osm2pgsql, and the same command arguments were used on both.

They both have the same pgsql configs. I have also run a vacuum and reindex on both and it still comes out to be off in size.

Are there any commands I should use to compare the indexes? Since these are load balanced servers and fault tolerant, I would prefer if they were as close as a mirror of each other.

Comment: Offtopic for stackoverflow which is about programming questions. Consider using http://gis.stackexchange.com/ or http://help.openstreetmap.org/